# Native File Browser Widget in SWT

Tags: java, swt

I'm looking to implement a file system browser as part of a project which abstracts a remote file system, through a database of permissions.  It should ideally appear as a native file system (visually) so I'm making use of SWT.  I have APIs to access the list of files and folders, but I have no access to native icons for things like folders and known file types as I understand it.

I was wondering if anyone knows of such a widget already that I can either modify or make use of?  If not does anyone have any suggestions for making a widget that will look native on all SWT supported platforms?

Just to be clear - I'm not looking for `FileDialog`, it needs to be a fully interactive widget, that I can just include in an SWT Display.  i.e. it needs to not be modal...

**EDIT**

A little clarification for why `FileDialog` is not what I'm looking for:

I looking to implement an Explorer/Finder style interface to a virtual file system.  I don't want a Modal Dialog that pops up and only has the capability to choose a file.  It will need to support dragging and dropping of files (Or at least allow me to implement this), and the standard native looking functions you'd expect from a file system.

Comment: Can you please clarify why `FileDialog` doesn't solve your problem? I don't quite understand your question.

Comment: @Baz I've edited the question with clarification - I hope that helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no "native file browser" that supports all the features you need.
The only similar things in SWT are `FileDialog` and `DirectoryDialog`.

There are some code examples that create a file browser with a couple of features you need, however, they obviously won't look like the native file browser. Here is an example I found:

- [File broswer](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/SWT-JFace-Eclipse/FileViewerexampleinSWT.htm)

Looks like this:

[image]